# Calculating total and average salary

Tags: java, url, io, java.util.scanner

The question says:  A university posts its employees' salaries at http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/Salary.txt. Each line in the file consists of a faculty member's

- first name,
- last name,
- rank,
- and salary.

Write a program to display the ***total salary*** for

- assistant professors,
- associate professors,
- full professors,
- and all faculty respectively,

and display the ***average salary*** for

- assistant professors,
- associate professors,
- full professors,
- and all faculty respectively.

And my code thus far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class Salary {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException{
        URL salary = new URL("http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/Salary.txt");
        try{
            Scanner read = new Scanner(salary.openStream());
            while(read.hasNextLine()){
                String line = read.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line); //Testing to see if the URL works
            }
            read.close();
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What I was hoping I could do would be to create objects from each line of text and then group them together based on their rank and go from there, however, I honestly can't figure out how to do that for the life of me. I think once I get everything grouped together the way I want it then I should be able to figure out the rest, but I'm not sure if I should even be doing all of this in the main method.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not going to do your homework, but this might help you:

- `line.split("\\s")` does split the line into an array of String, separated by white-space.
- `Double.valueOf(string)` converts a string into a double. Will throw an Exception if the String is actually not a number.
- Then - as you already suggested - putting the results in immutable data classes for easier processing should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

From you problem description I don't think you really care about the names of the faculty members. In that case for your problem I would suggest you use HashMap that maps from a key to an arraylist. something like

`HashMap<String, ArrayList<Float>> hs = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Float>>();`

Your `key` can be type of faculty i.e. assistant professors, associate professors, full professors etc and in arraylist you store there salaries so when you have to calculate total salaries, average salaries you only need to perform these operations on the individual arraylists which is nice and easy to do. You can use `.split(" ")` method to extract the individual parts from the line as you read it and as the format is similar for all the lines it won't break midway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you maybe have problems on transform the data from String to Double.
In my opinion, why not process the data in the while loop? 
such as

```
String first_name,last_name,rank;
double salary;
first_name=read.next();
last_name=read.next();
rank=read.next;
salary=read.next_Double();
```

//the definition should put out of the while loop
(next()double is not permitted in the text, use next_Double to sub)
then you get the data you want, and you can process it easily.
hope this can help you.